# Approaches for generic, compile-time safe lazy-load methods

Tags: c#, generics, lazy-loading

Suppose I have created a wrapper class like the following:

```
public class Foo : IFoo
{
    private readonly IFoo innerFoo;

    public Foo(IFoo innerFoo)
    {
        this.innerFoo = innerFoo;
    }

    public int? Bar { get; set; }
    public int? Baz { get; set; }
}
```

The idea here is that the `innerFoo` might wrap data-access methods or something similarly expensive, and I only want its `GetBar` and `GetBaz` methods to be invoked once.  So I want to create *another* wrapper around it, which will save the values obtained on the first run.

It's simple enough to do this, of course:

```
int IFoo.GetBar()
{
    if ((Bar == null) && (innerFoo != null))
        Bar = innerFoo.GetBar();
    return Bar ?? 0;
}

int IFoo.GetBaz()
{
    if ((Baz == null) && (innerFoo != null))
        Baz = innerFoo.GetBaz();
    return Baz ?? 0;
}
```

But it gets pretty repetitive if I'm doing this with 10 different properties and 30 different wrappers.  So I figured, hey, let's make this generic:

```
T LazyLoad<T>(ref T prop, Func<IFoo, T> loader)
{
    if ((prop == null) && (innerFoo != null))
        prop = loader(innerFoo);
    return prop;
}
```

Which *almost* gets me where I want, but not quite, because you can't `ref` an auto-property (or any property at all).  In other words, I can't write this:

```
int IFoo.GetBar()
{
    return LazyLoad(ref Bar, f => f.GetBar());  // <--- Won't compile
}
```

Instead, I'd have to change `Bar` to have an explicit backing field and write explicit getters and setters.  Which is fine, except for the fact that I end up writing even more redundant code than I was writing in the first place.

Then I considered the possibility of using expression trees:

```
T LazyLoad<T>(Expression<Func<T>> propExpr, Func<IFoo, T> loader)
{
    var memberExpression = propExpr.Body as MemberExpression;
    if (memberExpression != null)
    {
        // Use Reflection to inspect/set the property
    }
}
```

This plays nice with *refactoring* - it'll work great if I do this:

```
return LazyLoad(f => f.Bar, f => f.GetBar());
```

But it's not actually **safe**, because someone less clever (i.e. myself in 3 days from now when I inevitably forget how this is implemented internally) could decide to write this instead:

```
return LazyLoad(f => 3, f => f.GetBar());
```

Which is either going to crash or result in unexpected/undefined behaviour, depending on how defensively I write the `LazyLoad` method.  So I don't really like this approach either, because it leads to the possibility of runtime errors which would have been prevented in the first attempt.  It also relies on Reflection, which feels a little dirty here, even though this code is admittedly not performance-sensitive.

Now I *could* also decide to go all-out and use DynamicProxy to do method interception and not have to write *any* code, and in fact I *already* do this in some applications.  But this code is residing in a core library which many other assemblies depend on, and it seems *horribly* wrong to be introducing this kind of complexity at such a low level.  Separating the interceptor-based implementation from the `IFoo` interface by putting it into its own assembly doesn't really help; the fact is that this very class is still going to be used all over the place, *must* be used, so this isn't one of those problems that could be trivially solved with a little DI magic.

The last option I've already thought of would be to have a method like:

```
 T LazyLoad<T>(Func<T> getter, Action<T> setter, Func<IFoo, T> loader) { ... }
```

This option is very "meh" as well - it avoids Reflection but is still error-prone, *and* it doesn't really reduce the repetition that much.  It's almost as bad as having to write explicit getters and setters for each property.

Maybe I'm just being incredibly nit-picky, but this application is still in its early stages, and it's going to grow substantially over time, and I really want to keep the code squeaky-clean.

Bottom line: I'm at an impasse, looking for other ideas.

## Question:

Is there any way to clean up the lazy-loading code at the top, such that the implementation will:

- Guarantee compile-time safety, like the `ref` version;
- Actually *reduce* the amount of code repetition, like the `Expression` version; and
- Not take on any significant additional dependencies?

In other words, is there a way to do this just using regular C# language features and possibly a few small helper classes?  Or am I just going to have to accept that there's a trade-off here and strike one of the above requirements from the list?

Comment: Do you really need to have a public readable/writable property that may or may not be populated AND a public GetX() that sets the property and returns the value?

Comment: @Jeffrey: Long story short, yes, because part of the rationale for this class is that the properties might be eagerly-loaded instead. For example, if the object wraps several database calls, a higher-level component might instead decide to load several of these from a large recordset in order to avoid repeated database calls.  I'm open to separating these functions - *if* the end result still meets all 3 criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up implementing something that's *kinda sorta* similar to the `Lazy` class in .NET 4, but more customized to the specific notion of "caching" as opposed to "lazy loading".

The quasi-lazy class looks like this:

```
public class CachedValue<T>
{
    private Func<T> initializer;
    private bool isValueCreated;
    private T value;

    public CachedValue(Func<T> initializer)
    {
        if (initializer == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("initializer");
        this.initializer = initializer;
    }

    public CachedValue(T value)
    {
        this.value = value;
        this.isValueCreated = true;
    }

    public static implicit operator T(CachedValue<T> lazy)
    {
        return (lazy != null) ? lazy.Value : default(T);
    }

    public static implicit operator CachedValue<T>(T value)
    {
        return new CachedValue<T>(value);
    }

    public bool IsValueCreated
    {
        get { return isValueCreated; }
    }

    public T Value
    {
        get
        {
            if (!isValueCreated)
            {
                value = initializer();
                isValueCreated = true;
            }
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

The idea is, unlike the `Lazy<T>` class, this can also be initialized from a *specific value*.  I also implemented some implicit conversion operators, so that it's possible to directly assign values to `CachedValue<T>` properties as though they were just `T`.  I didn't implement the thread-safety features of `Lazy<T>` - these instances are not designed to be passed around.

Then, since it's very verbose to instantiate these things, I took advantage of some generic type inference features to create a more compact lazy-init syntax:

```
public static class Deferred
{
    public static CachedValue<T> From<TSource, T>(TSource source, 
        Func<TSource, T> selector)
    {
        Func<T> initializer = () =>
            (source != null) ? selector(source) : default(T);
        return new CachedValue<T>(initializer);
    }
}
```

At the end of the day, what this gets me is an almost-POCO class using auto-properties that are initialized with deferred loaders in the constructor (which are null-coalescing from `Deferred`):

```
public class CachedFoo : IFoo
{
    public CachedFoo(IFoo innerFoo)
    {
        Bar = Deferred.From(innerFoo, f => f.GetBar());
        Baz = Deferred.From(innerFoo, f => f.GetBaz());
    }

    int IFoo.GetBar()
    {
        return Bar;
    }

    int IFoo.GetBaz()
    {
        return Baz;
    }

    public CachedValue<int> Bar { get; set; }
    public CachedValue<int> Baz { get; set; }
}
```

I'm not *absolutely thrilled* with this, but I am *pretty happy* with it.  What's good is that it also lets outsiders populate the properties in an implementation-agnostic way, which is very useful when I want to override the lazy-loading behaviour, i.e. to preload a bunch of records from a big SQL query:

```
CachedFoo foo = new CachedFoo(myFoo);
foo.Bar = 42;
foo.Baz = 86;
```

I'm sticking with this for now.  It seems pretty hard to screw up a wrapper class with this approach.  Because of the implicit conversion operator being used, it's even safe against `null` instances.

It still has a somewhat hackish feel, and I'm still open to better ideas.

Answer (score 4):

If you can use .NET 4, you should just use [`Lazy<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331.aspx).

It provides the functionality you are after, and, in addition, is fully thread-safe.

If you are not able to use .NET 4, I'd still recommend looking at it, and "stealing" it's design and API.  It makes lazy instantiation quite easy.

Comment: I did look into that class (still on .NET 3.5, but I could implement that myself) - but wasn't really able to work out how I would fit it into the design, keeping in mind that `innerFoo` might actually be `null` and that external classes should be able to change the property values (hence the public setters).  Maybe I'm just not seeing the forest for the trees - could you perhaps include an example of how this would look using `Lazy<T>`?

Answer (score 1):

If all you're trying to do is avoid replicating this code 300 times:

```
private int? bar;
public int Bar
{
    get
    {
        if (bar == null && innerFoo != null)
           bar = innerFoo.GetBar();
        return bar ?? 0;           
    }
    set
    {
        bar = value;
    }
}
```

Then you could always just create an indexer.

```
enum FooProperties
{
    Bar,
    Baz,
}

object[] properties = new object[2];

public object this[FooProperties property]
{
    get
    {
        if (properties[property] == null)
        {
           properties[property] = GetProperty(property);
        }
        return properties[property];           
    }
    set
    {
        properties[property] = value;
    }
}

private object GetProperty(FooProperties property)
{
    switch (property)
    {
         case FooProperties.Bar:
              if (innerFoo != null)
                  return innerFoo.GetBar();
              else
                  return (int)0;

         case FooProperties.Baz:
              if (innerFoo != null)
                  return innerFoo.GetBaz();
              else
                  return (int)0;

         default:
              throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
    }
}
```

This will require casting the value when it's read:

```
int myBar = (int)myFoo[FooProperties.Bar];
```

But it avoids most of the other problems.

EDITED TO ADD:

OK, here's what you should do, but don't tell anybody that you did it, or that I suggested it. Go with this option:

```
int IFoo.GetBar()
{
    return LazyLoad(ref Bar, f => f.GetBar());  // <--- Won't compile
}
```

Making `Bar`, `Baz`, and friends public fields instead of properties. That should be exactly what you're looking for.

But, again, don't tell anybody that you did that!

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the response.  I'm not sure that I'd want to go with this, as the indexer and enumeration would need to be custom-written for every lazy class, and the null check is still being repeated several times (just in a different place). It's sort of grouping all the ugliness together, which is an improvement, but I want to eliminate it entirely. ;)

Comment: @Aaronaught - I added another (secret) option to my answer.